# Conditions for a map inducing the trivial homomorphism to be null homotopic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Background: I'm reading Chapter 9 of Munkres *Topology* on the fundamental group, and Lemma 55.3. which is referenced many times states that, given a continuous map $h:S^1 \to X$, the following are equivalent

*(1) $h$ is null-homotopic*

*(2) $h$ extends to a continuous map $k:B^2 \to X$*

*(3) $h_*$ is the trivial homomorphism of fundamental groups*

Additionally, I proved earlier that if $h:(A,a_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ with $A\subset X$ and $X$ is simply connected, then if $h$ extends to a map $\tilde{h}:(X,a_0) \to (Y,y_0)$, then $h_*$ is the trivial homomorphism. The idea in this proof was to suppose there is an extension $\tilde{h}$, thus $h = \iota|_A \circ \tilde{h}$, and $h_* = \iota_{A,*} \circ \tilde{h}_*$, and since $\iota|_{A,*}:\pi_1(A,a_0) \to \pi_1(X,a_0) = 0$, we have that $h_*$ is the trivial homomorphism.

With this in mind, I have two questions:

1) Given a map $f:(X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ with $\pi_1(X,x_0) \neq [1_{x_0}]$, if $f_*:\pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is trivial, then is $f$ null-homotopic?

2) If the answer to 1) is yes, is the following generalization of the lemma above is true?

Let $A \subset X$ and $h:(A,a_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ with $\pi_1(A,a_0) \neq 0$ and $X$ simply connected. Then TFAE:

*(a) $h$ is null-homotopic*

*(b) $h$ extends to a continuous map $\tilde{h}:(X,a_0) \to (Y,y_0)$*

*(c) $h_*$ is the trivial homomorphism*

All I can prove so far is $(a) \implies (c)$ and $(b)\implies (c)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. You can, for example, without too much difficulty find a degree-one mapping of $S^1\times S^1$ to $S^2$. Of course, $S^2$ is simply connected, but the mapping cannot be null-homotopic.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, but are there any further conditions that force a mapping that induces a trivial homomorphism to be null-homotopic, that you know of?

Comment: Even requiring that the induced map on *all* homotopy groups is the zero-map won't do it. The closest I can think of is the Whitehead Theorem (see Hatcher or your favorite more advanced algebraic topology book): It says that if $f\colon X\to Y$ induces isomorphisms on *all* homotopy groups, then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Ill look into this in due time. Thank you!